# Stepper motor going 1 step forward and 1 backward

Tags: raspberry-pi, stepper-motor, gpio, python

I am trying to control stepper motors using Raspberry Pi 4 and I am facing an issue with it. I am using [L9110](https://www.elecrow.com/download/datasheet-l9110.pdf) controller, and the stepper motor is made for 12v/0.4A. I have a power supply and everything.

When I try to move my stepper motor it only goes 1 step forward and 1 step backward despite changing everything I could think of. If it matters I am using python and modulating the motor with GPIO using HIGH/LOW.

So I don't know if it is a problem with wiring, controller, or my software.

This is my code and it's the only way it was even possible to move the motor:

```
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

StepPins = [24,25,8,7]

for pin in StepPins:
      print(”setup”)
      GPIO.setup(pin, GPIO.OUT)
      GPIO.output(pin, False)

for x in range(200):
    GPIO.output(StepPins[2], GPIO.HIGH)
    GPIO.output(StepPins[3], GPIO.HIGH)
    time.sleep(0.02)
    GPIO.output(StepPins[0], GPIO.HIGH)
    GPIO.output(StepPins[1], GPIO.HIGH)
    time.sleep(0.02)
   
    GPIO.output(StepPins[2], GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(StepPins[3], GPIO.LOW)
    time.sleep(0.02)
    GPIO.output(StepPins[0], GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(StepPins[1], GPIO.LOW)
    time.sleep(0.02)
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Please show a schematic of how you have everything wired up.

Comment: Also please define the I/O pins. What are the inputs to your controller? Do the I/Os control the phases directly? Or are the inputs Clock, Direction, etc?

Comment: It is not possible to set both outputs of L9110 high at the same time, so it is very important to see how you route the motor coils to the driver chips. I'm afraid that it might be impossible to use these chips in a stepper context.

Comment: Do you have two L9110 chips per motor or only one? You need two. Please post a diagram showing how you've wired everything, and then we'll probably be able to see what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

This board is a dual half bridge (push-pull) for each winding, such that if both ports are high or low, it is equivalent to a zero torque with that winding and acts as a brake if it is moving.

The port pattern for stepping in one direction will be as follows and the opposite to reverse.  For maximum speed, you will want to reduce your step delay to allow acceleration without slipping.

This is for full steps.

1 0 0 0
0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0
0 0 0 1

1 0 0 0
0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0
0 0 0 1

1 0 0 0
0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0
0 0 0 1

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to add to the previous answer: You will need to use a function that changes all four of the GPIOs at the same time.  As you have it coded now, there are small delays as each GPIO is changed, putting the motor control signals in an undesirable state for short periods of time.  Stepper motors really don't react well to that.